# Grails MySQL connection

Tags: mysql, grails, ggts

When I try to connect to MySQL on GGTS I get the following error thrown:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad artifact coordinates mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin, expected format is :[:[:]]:

I am running GGTS on Ubuntu on a VM.

I have read that there was a problem with Windows. Could that be similar with Ubuntu?

Comment: Please post your `grails-app/conf/application.groovy` file. This is a configuration error.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have configured correctly grails data sources in `grails-app/conf/application.groovy`.

It should be something like these:

```
dataSource {
    dbCreate = "update"
    url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_database"
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    username = "username"
    password = "password"
}
```

Keep in mind that if you have a specific configuration for your current execution environment (e.g. production), you must edit the relative configuration:

```
environments {
    production {
        dataSource {
            url = "jdbc:mysql://liveip.com/liveDb"
            // other environment-specific settings here
        }
    }
}
```

For a complete reference see the [grails data source documentation](https://grails.org/single-page-documentation.html#dataSource).

Comment: Depending on your character set to support, and the MySQL DB creation, you might also want/need to include "?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8" on the end of your jdbc url.